# php insert into mysql success and return insert id, but no record in mysql database,why?

Tags: php, mysql

php insert into mysql success and return insert id, but no record in mysql database, mysql query is as below:

```
INSERT INTO `#__vc_transactions` SET `title`='现金币' , `units`='3' , `txn_id`='5FF0BDB3C815A69C' , `txn_amount`='3' , `txn_currency`='CNY' , `txn_status`='pending' , `txn_date`='2016-12-23 06:32:38' , `extra_data`=NULL , `service_provider`='System' , `service_alias`='' , `item_id`='2' , `item_type`='currency' , `sender_id`='0' , `receiver_id`='50' , `custom_price`='0' , `order_status`='transfer' , `transfer_type`='1' , `bank`='1'
```

But meanwhile another alternative query as below is ok, which record in mysql database.

```
INSERT INTO `#__vc_transactions` SET `title`='现金币' , `units`='50' , `txn_id`='8DE6C35ED5CD9569' , `txn_amount`='45' , `txn_currency`='CNY' , `txn_status`='completed' , `txn_date`='2016-12-23 06:32:00' , `extra_data`='手续费:5' , `service_provider`='System' , `service_alias`='' , `item_id`='2' , `item_type`='currency' , `sender_id`='50' , `receiver_id`='47' , `custom_price`='0' , `order_status`='transfer' , `transfer_type`='2' , `bank`='0'
```

WHY?What is problem of the first query ?

**UPDATE**
Also I change another query statment, and the result is the same and issue is the same
It works as below:

```
INSERT INTO `#__vc_transactions` (`title`,`units`,`txn_id`,`txn_amount`,`txn_currency`,`txn_status`,`txn_date`,`extra_data`,`service_provider`,`service_alias`,`item_id`,`item_type`,`sender_id`,`receiver_id`,`custom_price`,`order_status`,`transfer_type`,`bank`) VALUES ('现金币','50','EE2CE817052183C2','45','CNY','completed','2016-12-28 02:33:00','手续费:5','系统','','2','currency','50','47','0','transfer','2','0')
```

It doesn't work as below:

```
INSERT INTO `#__vc_transactions` (`title`,`units`,`txn_id`,`txn_amount`,`txn_currency`,`txn_status`,`txn_date`,`extra_data`,`service_provider`,`service_alias`,`item_id`,`item_type`,`sender_id`,`receiver_id`,`custom_price`,`order_status`,`transfer_type`,`bank`) VALUES ('现金币','1','C5EAE30FBC59425F','1','CNY','pending','2016-12-28 02:34:35',NULL,'系统','','2','currency','0','50','0','transfer','1','1')
```

Comment: The `SET` command goes with `UPDATE`, not `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: You should be using `UPDATE #__vc_transactions SET ...`, but as to why one worked and one failed, I have no explanation, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: try using " ` " instead of " ' " in values

Comment: I have change such query but the issue is the same!Please check my update

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the `SET` command works with `INSERT` as well. It's just  not widely used.

Comment: Try running the query directly into MySQL rather than using PHP. That way you can narrow down if PHP is the problem or the database itself. You should also show your PHP code. It isn't possible for anyone to know if the problem is there without seeing it.  I *suspect* it's character encoding related.

Comment: does the `extra_data` field accept `NULL`? also check if there is any triggers which is preventing the insert

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO `#__vc_transactions` (`title`, `units`, ...) VALUES ('abc', '3', ...);
```

Comment: I have change such query but the issue is the same!Please check my update